# C# refreshing a chart every few seconds

Tags: c#, charts

I have a Windows Forms App written in C#. The idea is, that it draws a chart for 10 numbers after clicking a button. This works fine. I click the button, and I get a nice chart. However I also want to include a sort of "auto refresh" mode, where the chart is refreshed every few seconds. This would be enabled via `Checkbox`. Here's my code:

```
private void chartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //draw a chart after the button is clicked
{
   Random rdn1 = new Random();
   int value;

   foreach (var series in ekran.Series) //clear previous values
   {
      series.Points.Clear();
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) //draw a chart from ten new values
   {
      value = rdn1.Next(0, 10); //for testing purpouses the value will be a random number a random number
      ekran.Series["seria1"].Points.AddXY(i, value);
   }
}

private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   while(checkBox1.Checked) //click the chartButton every one second, when the checkbox is checked
   {
      //rysuj.PerformClick(); 
      chartButton.PerformClick();
      Thread.Sleep(1000);
   }
}
```

And now for my problem. When I check the `Checkbox`, I will not get a chart until it finishes every iteration of the while loop. Since it's an infinite loop, I will never get my chart. If I rewrite the code to make only five iterations when the `Checkbox` is checked, I only get the chart for the fifth one (and after five seconds, as to be expected).

So my question is: how can I force this to draw a chart every time the button is clicked via `chartButton.PerformClick()`? When I click the button manually, everything works fine, it's just when I try to do it automatically, I get my problem.

EDIT
First of all,thank you for the replies. However, I'm still experiencing the same problem when using a timer. This is how my code looks now:

```
namespace ChartTest
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
        timer.Interval = 1000;
    }

    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Enabled = false;
        chartButton.PerformClick();

    }        

    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        while (checkBox1.Checked)            
        {
            timer.Enabled = true;                       // Enable the timer
            timer.Start();                              // Start the timer
        }

    }

    private void chartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)      //draw a chart after the button is clicked
    {
        Random rdn1 = new Random();
        int value;

        ekran.Series.Clear();

        var series2 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series
        {
            Name = "Series2",
            Color = System.Drawing.Color.Green,
            IsVisibleInLegend = false,
            IsXValueIndexed = true,
            ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line
        };
        this.ekran.Series.Add(series2);

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            value = rdn1.Next(0, 10);
            series2.Points.AddXY(i, value);
        }

    }

}
}
```

Sorry for being a total noob, but I have no idea, what am I doing wrong this time.

Comment: You're probably looking for a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`.

Comment: The while loop is freezing your UI thread. Either use a timer or a backgroundworker. It have been asked many, many times before, look around on either SO or Google and you'll find plenty of resources.

Comment: It is a very bad coding practice to call events from within your code.  Use a timer as @adv12 has suggested.

Comment: Thanks very much! But I still have problems. I edited my question and added the details

Comment: Two things: First, remove the `timer.Enabled = false;` line from the `timer_Tick` handler. As I mentioned below, that causes the timer to stop and not tick anymore. Second, in your `checkBox1_checkChanged` handler, get rid of the `while` statement - this is causing your more immediate problem. Instead, change the whole method to a single line: `timer.Enabled = checkBox1.Checked;`

Comment: Thank you very much! Now everything works fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what a `Timer` is for. Have the checkbox start/stop or enable/disable the timer, and handle the `Timer.Tick` event to redraw your chart. In your case, the event handler could simply call `chartButton.PerformClick()`, or insert whatever code the `PerformClick()` does.

ETA: If the chart refresh is not instant, you will probably want to push it off to a separate thread. If it's instant, there's not really any need to deal with the threading though.

Comment: even if the chart refresh is not instantaneous, there's little to gain from threading.  UI controls are not threadsafe, so modifying them from a background thread is not permitted.  To be "correct," the background thread would have to marshall all the UI changes via `Control.Invoke`, which means the changes would all ultimately happen on the UI thread anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I would go the route of using a thread with combination of checkbox's checkChange() event. Essentially this will allow your application to keep running while the update code will execute periodically. The refresh is determined by the sleep time, not your manual click or any other value.. Example below on how I to do this:

```
Thread refreshThread = null;

private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (refreshThread == null) //No thread running, assume it starts this way
   {
      refreshThread = new Thread(chartRefresh);
      refreshThread.Start();
   }
   else //Thread is running, must terminate
   {
      refreshThread.Abort();
      refreshThread = null;
   }
}

private void chartRefresh()
{
   while (true)
   {
      //code to refresh chart
      Thread.Sleep(10000);
   }
}
```

Comment: Threading comes with a lot of gotchas, for instance the fact that all access to GUI controls in your `chartRefresh` method must be dispatched via `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke` to avoid illegal cross-thread calls.  `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` encapsulates the functionality you're trying to provide and is much safer to use for all but the smartest and most experienced programmers.